# Error When Registering Header in UICollectionViewCell iOS Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, header, uicollectionview

I'm doing Let's Built That App's twitter remake tutorial and I keep coming across this error: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter with identifier headerId - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'. I try to register the header below but my app still gives me the same error. This is the link to the video: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2fcf9yFe944&list=PL0dzCUj1L5JE1wErjzEyVqlvx92VN3DL5

```
let cellId = "cellId"
let headerId = "headerId"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView?.backgroundColor = .white
    collectionView?.register(WordCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    collectionView?.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: headerId)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You registered that view as `UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader` but are trying to use it as `UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter`.  These details are key.

You can check to make sure the `collectionView` method is getting the correct type by doing something like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
  if kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader {
     //Now you can dequeue your view with reuseId "headerId"
  } else {
     //This is where you set the footerView, if you are using one
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean? How did I use it as a 'UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter'?

Comment: In that `viewForSupplementaryElement` method for UICollectionView you need to make sure the `kind` field matches the type you registered a class for.